# Can't see test files

Tags: android, android-studio, robolectric

I'm trying to get robolectic junit tests workin in Android Studio. I've downloaded this sample https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-samples and selected "Import non-android Studio project", and selected the top level `build.gradle` file.

So here is a path to a test file which looks correct to me:

```
robolectric-samples/android-api-21/src/test/java/com/example/activity/MainActivityTest.java
```

But in android studio there is no sign of the *Test.java files.

[image: Where is the test]

Comment: did you sync your gradle files?

Comment: Not sure - how do I do that? I did run `./gradlew test` which runs without error but doesn't appear to run the tests.

Comment: usually android studio tells you to do that right after editing a gradle file. you can manually do that by clicking the menu icon "Sync Project with Gradle Files"

Comment: I can't see that but I've tried File->Synchronize.

Comment: No, that's not the right one. Click the icon on the same row with the gradle icon and arrow within. I just can't find it in the top menu either... This should sync your project structure. For cmd line builds this is not needed.

Comment: Got it: Tools->Android->Sync Project with Gradle Files

Comment: It half works. I see the Tests blue folder next to java briefly then it disappears.

Comment: OK, going to drop back to the stable release. Might be my fault installing bleeding edge (canary).

Comment: Yep, sounds like a visual bug... Is it working now?

Comment: No luck in 1.0.2 either.

Comment: hm. how did you import this sample? just tried and everything looks fine here...

Comment: @clash Thanks for trying it. I selected Import non-android Studio project, and selected the main build.gradle

Comment: I worked before only with robolectric gradle plugin. These test are using different. I know that there is special AS plugin for this gradle plugin. But without it you could also add next section to your `build.gradle` `android` section `sourceSets {androidTest.setRoot( 'src/test' )}` but you should also probably duplicate your test dependencies with `androidTestCompile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the [Android Studio Unit test plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7488) for Android Studio to pick up the src/test/java folder.

Comment: It worked, but when I came back to the project they were all gone again. Ever see that?

Comment: Sometimes, a (gradle) refresh of the project fixes that for me.